# Web Essentials Zen Coding and Razor syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, web-essentials

When using Web Essentials in a Razor View, I get some unexpected behavior out of the HTML zen coding tab complete.

Starting here

```
<div class="panel-body">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Workflow", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        div.form-group//cursor here
    }
</div>
```

when I hit tab, I expect it to expand to

```
<div class="panel-body">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Workflow", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="form-group"></div>
    }
</div>
```

but instead it expands to

```
<div class="panel-body">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Workflow", FormMethod.Post))
            {
        < div class="form-group"></div>
    }
</div>
```

Which is close but... strange.

Is there something I can do to effectively use zen coding in a Razor view?

Comment: Maybe your visual studio is interfering with zen, Have you tried disabling format on paste?(Tools->Options->Text Editor->HTML->Advanced)

Comment: @lkn2993 I just tried, no dice unfortunately.